# Google Ads skip video button bug

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I use GADRewardBasedVideoAd. If I watch the video to the end it works fine, but when I press the skip video button after 5 sec. The Video ad is being dismissed, but so is the view that presented the add. Any help would be appreciated. I do nothing special, I just present the add like this

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print(rewardBasedVideoAd)
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't get a useful answer here, file a ticket on their forum.